# How to find driver under inode?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Suppose I have pointer to struct inode, references some special file. 
How it can be found which driver is placed under this inode?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot deduce driver from the `inode` object. But if driver is compiled as module, the way below may help.

You can check `inode->i_fop->owner` field. If it is non-NULL, it refers to the module (`struct module`), which implements it. Macro `module_name(mod)` returns name of that module.

Comment: How it can be done at all? I need find function called when device file opened (all sources are accessible).

Comment: The first driver's function, called when device file opened, is one referenced by `inode->i_fop->open` field. You can print its name using `%pf` specified of printk, and then search through sources.